# About generalization of $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If there's a hyperbola of the form $$y = \frac{ax + b}{cx - a}$$ then the hyperbola and its inverse will always be same.

**Can this be generalized more in any sense?**

One obvious thing that could be done is we can multiply and divide $f(x)$ by another polynomial $g(x)$ and the result will still hold.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiply and divide f(x) by another polynomial g(x)"? Doesn't that only give you $f(x)$ (maybe with a bunch of holes)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See the very interesting "History" part in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root calling $f(f(x))=x$  "Babbage functional equation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact type of generalization that you have in your mind. But since you said "in any sense", I will say a few things about the maximum possible generalization: **Involutive Functions**

An involution is a function $f: X\to X$ whose inverse is itself. That is, $$f\circ f=\operatorname{id}_X$$ A function is an involution if and only if the underlying relation is symmetric. When $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R},$ this fact can be seen as the graph of $f$ being symmetric around the line $y=x.$

The example gave you $$y=\dfrac{ax+b}{cx-a}$$ is an involution of $\mathbb{R}$ which can also extend easily to $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\},$ or even to the Rienamm sphere $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}.$ And there are many more such functions. Another example is $$y=\dfrac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}.$$

**Added Later**:
Consider the function $a\mapsto 9a$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ (integers modulo $20$). It is not difficult to see that this is an involution. Likewise, in general, there are many exotic examples.